# FullCalendar - Multiple Google Calendars

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

My JS code:

```
$(function() {
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    googleCalendarApiKey: 'key',
    events: {
        googleCalendarId: 'dontdoxmepls@group.calendar.google.com'
        googleCalendarId: 'nodoxpls.co.uk_tmu7vco31e7raj9ce11a64qd08@group.calendar.google.com'
    }
    });
});
```

The calendar doesn't even render itself when I load the page. Google Chrome console says 'Unexpected Identifier', presumably due to there being two calendars. Is there a way I can load more than one GCal at once?

If anyone's curious as to why, I'm intending to make a custom filter for the calendars so that users can select what type of events they want to show on the calendar, and each page will have different combinations of calendars.

Doubt this is relevant, but for the sake of thoroughness: Chrome 70.0.3538.102, VS Code 1.29.1

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google-calendar shows an example of you how to do it - see the section entitled "Multiple Google Calendars". P.S. You're right you can't specify the same property twice in an object - how is the JavaScript interpreter supposed to tell the difference between them?

Comment: I have no clue how to mark this as solved, but thank you!

Comment: you can't because it was just a comment. I can post it as a full answer if you really like, but it would just be an almost exact copy of what's in that link I gave you (and which I'm a bit surprised you hadn't read already?)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    googleCalendarApiKey: 'AIzaSyCYI12U7MvN6tIDQuZT1OB67nxPNTnzBnw',
    eventSources: [
      {
        googleCalendarId:'kingsmonktonapps.co.uk_pe2i7pqioptt72bd8kvp8h1eno@group.calendar.google.com'
      },
      {
        googleCalendarId: 'kingsmonktonapps.co.uk_tmu7vco31e7raj9ce11a64qd08@group.calendar.google.com',

      }
    ]
  });
});
```